# Mouse scroll key not working in Chrome & Firefox on website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

Check this website - https://www.eviltech.in/

The mouse scroll key is not working in Google Chrome & Mozilla Firefox but it's working fine in Microsoft Edge.

[My webpage won't scroll down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167329/my-webpage-wont-scroll-down)

As suggested above the scroll key might not work if the CSS has `overflow:hidden` to `body` or `html` but that's not the case here. The scrollbar is visible in all browsers and the website can be scrolled by dragging the scrollbar.

Is there any other case where this might happen? What is the solution for that?

**UPDATE:**
The problem has been found in a javascript file `wow.js` by @ChrisHappy
I can't remove the entire wow.js from the website as it performs crucial animations required on the website.

Here are the `wow.js` codes:

```
(function() {
    var MutationObserver, Util, WeakMap, __bind = function(fn, me) {
            return function() {
                return fn.apply(me, arguments)
            }
        },
        __indexOf = [].indexOf || function(item) {
            for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) {
                if (i in this && this[i] === item) return i
            }
            return -1
        };
    Util = (function() {
        function Util() {}
        Util.prototype.extend = function(custom, defaults) {
            var key, value;
            for (key in custom) {
                value = custom[key];
                if (value != null) {
                    defaults[key] = value
                }
            }
            return defaults
        };
        Util.prototype.isMobile = function(agent) {
            return /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(agent)
        };
        return Util
    })();
    WeakMap = this.WeakMap || this.MozWeakMap || (WeakMap = (function() {
        function WeakMap() {
            this.keys = [];
            this.values = []
        }
        WeakMap.prototype.get = function(key) {
            var i, item, _i, _len, _ref;
            _ref = this.keys;
            for (i = _i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; i = ++_i) {
                item = _ref[i];
                if (item === key) {
                    return this.values[i]
                }
            }
        };
        WeakMap.prototype.set = function(key, value) {
            var i, item, _i, _len, _ref;
            _ref = this.keys;
            for (i = _i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; i = ++_i) {
                item = _ref[i];
                if (item === key) {
                    this.values[i] = value;
                    return
                }
            }
            this.keys.push(key);
            return this.values.push(value)
        };
        return WeakMap
    })());
    MutationObserver = this.MutationObserver || this.WebkitMutationObserver || this.MozMutationObserver || (MutationObserver = (function() {
        function MutationObserver() {
            console.warn('MutationObserver is not supported by your browser.');
            console.warn('WOW.js cannot detect dom mutations, please call .sync() after loading new content.')
        }
        MutationObserver.notSupported = !0;
        MutationObserver.prototype.observe = function() {};
        return MutationObserver
    })());
    this.WOW = (function() {
        WOW.prototype.defaults = {
            boxClass: 'wow',
            animateClass: 'animated',
            offset: 0,
            mobile: !0,
            live: !0
        };

        function WOW(options) {
            if (options == null) {
                options = {}
            }
            this.scrollCallback = __bind(this.scrollCallback, this);
            this.scrollHandler = __bind(this.scrollHandler, this);
            this.start = __bind(this.start, this);
            this.scrolled = !0;
            this.config = this.util().extend(options, this.defaults);
            this.animationNameCache = new WeakMap()
        }
        WOW.prototype.init = function() {
            var _ref;
            this.element = window.document.documentElement;
            if ((_ref = document.readyState) === "interactive" || _ref === "complete") {
                this.start()
            } else {
                document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', this.start)
            }
            return this.finished = []
        };
        WOW.prototype.start = function() {
            var box, _i, _len, _ref;
            this.stopped = !1;
            this.boxes = this.element.getElementsByClassName(this.config.boxClass);
            this.all = (function() {
                var _i, _len, _ref, _results;
                _ref = this.boxes;
                _results = [];
                for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
                    box = _ref[_i];
                    _results.push(box)
                }
                return _results
            }).call(this);
            if (this.boxes.length) {
                if (this.disabled()) {
                    this.resetStyle()
                } else {
                    _ref = this.boxes;
                    for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
                        box = _ref[_i];
                        this.applyStyle(box, !0)
                    }
                    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollHandler, !1);
                    window.addEventListener('resize', this.scrollHandler, !1);
                    this.interval = setInterval(this.scrollCallback, 50)
                }
            }
            if (this.config.live) {
                return new MutationObserver((function(_this) {
                    return function(records) {
                        var node, record, _j, _len1, _results;
                        _results = [];
                        for (_j = 0, _len1 = records.length; _j < _len1; _j++) {
                            record = records[_j];
                            _results.push((function() {
                                var _k, _len2, _ref1, _results1;
                                _ref1 = record.addedNodes || [];
                                _results1 = [];
                                for (_k = 0, _len2 = _ref1.length; _k < _len2; _k++) {
                                    node = _ref1[_k];
                                    _results1.push(this.doSync(node))
                                }
                                return _results1
                            }).call(_this))
                        }
                        return _results
                    }
                })(this)).observe(document.body, {
                    childList: !0,
                    subtree: !0
                })
            }
        };
        WOW.prototype.stop = function() {
            this.stopped = !0;
            window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.scrollHandler, !1);
            window.removeEventListener('resize', this.scrollHandler, !1);
            if (this.interval != null) {
                return clearInterval(this.interval)
            }
        };
        WOW.prototype.sync = function(element) {
            if (MutationObserver.notSupported) {
                return this.doSync(this.element)
            }
        };
        WOW.prototype.doSync = function(element) {
            var box, _i, _len, _ref, _results;
            if (!this.stopped) {
                element || (element = this.element);
                element = element.parentNode || element;
                _ref = element.getElementsByClassName(this.config.boxClass);
                _results = [];
                for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
                    box = _ref[_i];
                    if (__indexOf.call(this.all, box) < 0) {
                        this.applyStyle(box, !0);
                        this.boxes.push(box);
                        this.all.push(box);
                        _results.push(this.scrolled = !0)
                    } else {
                        _results.push(void 0)
                    }
                }
                return _results
            }
        };
        WOW.prototype.show = function(box) {
            this.applyStyle(box);
            return box.className = "" + box.className + " " + this.config.animateClass
        };
        WOW.prototype.applyStyle = function(box, hidden) {
            var delay, duration, iteration;
            duration = box.getAttribute('data-wow-duration');
            delay = box.getAttribute('data-wow-delay');
            iteration = box.getAttribute('data-wow-iteration');
            return this.animate((function(_this) {
                return function() {
                    return _this.customStyle(box, hidden, duration, delay, iteration)
                }
            })(this))
        };
        WOW.prototype.animate = (function() {
            if ('requestAnimationFrame' in window) {
                return function(callback) {
                    return window.requestAnimationFrame(callback)
                }
            } else {
                return function(callback) {
                    return callback()
                }
            }
        })();
        WOW.prototype.resetStyle = function() {
            var box, _i, _len, _ref, _results;
            _ref = this.boxes;
            _results = [];
            for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
                box = _ref[_i];
                _results.push(box.setAttribute('style', 'visibility: visible;'))
            }
            return _results
        };
        WOW.prototype.customStyle = function(box, hidden, duration, delay, iteration) {
            if (hidden) {
                this.cacheAnimationName(box)
            }
            box.style.visibility = hidden ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
            if (duration) {
                this.vendorSet(box.style, {
                    animationDuration: duration
                })
            }
            if (delay) {
                this.vendorSet(box.style, {
                    animationDelay: delay
                })
            }
            if (iteration) {
                this.vendorSet(box.style, {
                    animationIterationCount: iteration
                })
            }
            this.vendorSet(box.style, {
                animationName: hidden ? 'none' : this.cachedAnimationName(box)
            });
            return box
        };
        WOW.prototype.vendors = ["moz", "webkit"];
        WOW.prototype.vendorSet = function(elem, properties) {
            var name, value, vendor, _results;
            _results = [];
            for (name in properties) {
                value = properties[name];
                elem["" + name] = value;
                _results.push((function() {
                    var _i, _len, _ref, _results1;
                    _ref = this.vendors;
                    _results1 = [];
                    for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
                        vendor = _ref[_i];
                        _results1.push(elem["" + vendor + (name.charAt(0).toUpperCase()) + (name.substr(1))] = value)
                    }
                    return _results1
                }).call(this))
            }
            return _results
        };
        WOW.prototype.vendorCSS = function(elem, property) {
            var result, style, vendor, _i, _len, _ref;
            style = window.getComputedStyle(elem);
            result = style.getPropertyCSSValue(property);
            _ref = this.vendors;
            for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
                vendor = _ref[_i];
                result = result || style.getPropertyCSSValue("-" + vendor + "-" + property)
            }
            return result
        };
        WOW.prototype.animationName = function(box) {
            var animationName;
            try {
                animationName = this.vendorCSS(box, 'animation-name').cssText
            } catch (_error) {
                animationName = window.getComputedStyle(box).getPropertyValue('animation-name')
            }
            if (animationName === 'none') {
                return ''
            } else {
                return animationName
            }
        };
        WOW.prototype.cacheAnimationName = function(box) {
            return this.animationNameCache.set(box, this.animationName(box))
        };
        WOW.prototype.cachedAnimationName = function(box) {
            return this.animationNameCache.get(box)
        };
        WOW.prototype.scrollHandler = function() {
            return this.scrolled = !0
        };
        WOW.prototype.scrollCallback = function() {
            var box;
            if (this.scrolled) {
                this.scrolled = !1;
                this.boxes = (function() {
                    var _i, _len, _ref, _results;
                    _ref = this.boxes;
                    _results = [];
                    for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
                        box = _ref[_i];
                        if (!(box)) {
                            continue
                        }
                        if (this.isVisible(box)) {
                            this.show(box);
                            continue
                        }
                        _results.push(box)
                    }
                    return _results
                }).call(this);
                if (!(this.boxes.length || this.config.live)) {
                    return this.stop()
                }
            }
        };
        WOW.prototype.offsetTop = function(element) {
            var top;
            while (element.offsetTop === void 0) {
                element = element.parentNode
            }
            top = element.offsetTop;
            while (element = element.offsetParent) {
                top += element.offsetTop
            }
            return top
        };
        WOW.prototype.isVisible = function(box) {
            var bottom, offset, top, viewBottom, viewTop;
            offset = box.getAttribute('data-wow-offset') || this.config.offset;
            viewTop = window.pageYOffset;
            viewBottom = viewTop + this.element.clientHeight - offset;
            top = this.offsetTop(box);
            bottom = top + box.clientHeight;
            return top <= viewBottom && bottom >= viewTop
        };
        WOW.prototype.util = function() {
            return this._util || (this._util = new Util())
        };
        WOW.prototype.disabled = function() {
            return !this.config.mobile && this.util().isMobile(navigator.userAgent)
        };
        return WOW
    })()
}).call(this)
```

Is it possible to remove the lines of codes which are affecting the scrolling without affecting other functionalities here?

**UPDATE 2:** I tried removing entire `wow.js` but still the scrolling was not fixed and lots of vital functions stopped working.
That means the issue is not with the `wow.js` file.

Is there anything else that might be causing this issue?

Comment: Tested in Chrome: works fine

Comment: Well, it's from JS. Disable it and see. I would recommend removing all libraries then adding them back one by one and see which one causes the issue. God bless!

Comment: @ChrisHappy the JS is crucial for the website. I have combined them to increase the page speed. You can see all the JS files separately here: https://www.eviltech.in/seo can you tell me which file is causing the issue?

Comment: Update, it's from wow.js

Comment: Quick solution, remove `/js/wow.js` I can't say I know what inside is causing it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was problem in the JS file `rd-smoothscroll.min.js`
Removing the entire JS files has solved the problem.

```
! function(t, i, o) {
    "use strict";
    var e = "ontouchstart" in t,
        r = ("undefined" != typeof InstallTrigger, "webkitTransform" in i.documentElement.style);
    t.requestAnimFrame = function() {
        return t.requestAnimationFrame || t.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || t.mozRequestAnimationFrame || t.oRequestAnimationFrame || t.msRequestAnimationFrame || function(i) {
            t.setTimeout(i, 1e3 / 60)
        }
    }(), t.RDSmoothScroll = function() {
        this.options = RDSmoothScroll.Defaults, this.animators = [], this.initialize()
    }, RDSmoothScroll.Defaults = {
        friction: .95,
        step: 2,
        minDistance: .1
    }, RDSmoothScroll.Animator = function(t) {
        var i = "html" === t.nodeName.toLowerCase() && r ? t.children[t.children.length - 1] : t;
        this.target = t, this.originalTarget = i, this.direction = o, this.currentY = i.scrollTop, this.targetY = i.scrollTop, this.lastY = i.scrollTop, this.delta = 0, this.minY = 0, this.maxY = o, this.isPlaying = !1, this.speed = 0
    }, RDSmoothScroll.Animator.prototype.update = function(i) {
        var o = t.RDSmoothScroll.instance,
            e = i.detail ? -1 * i.detail : i.wheelDelta / 40,
            r = 0 > e ? -1 : 1;
        r != this.direction && (this.speed = 0, this.direction = r), this.currentY = -this.originalTarget.scrollTop, this.delta = e, this.targetY += e, this.speed += (this.targetY - this.lastY) * o.options.step, this.lastY = this.targetY, this.start()
    }, RDSmoothScroll.Animator.prototype.start = function() {
        this.isPlaying || (this.isPlaying = !0, t.jQuery && t.jQuery(this.originalTarget).stop(), this.play())
    }, RDSmoothScroll.Animator.prototype.play = function() {
        var t = this;
        this.isPlaying && (requestAnimFrame(function() {
            t.play()
        }), this.render())
    }, RDSmoothScroll.Animator.prototype.stop = function() {
        this.isPlaying && (this.speed = 0, this.isPlaying = !1)
    }, RDSmoothScroll.Animator.prototype.render = function() {
        var i = t.RDSmoothScroll.instance;
        Math.abs(this.originalTarget.scrollTop - -this.currentY) > Math.abs(this.delta) && Math.abs(this.originalTarget.scrollTop - -this.currentY) > 1 && this.stop(), this.speed < -i.options.minDistance || this.speed > i.options.minDistance ? (this.currentY = this.currentY + this.speed, this.currentY > this.minY ? this.currentY = this.speed = 0 : this.currentY < this.maxY && (this.speed = 0, this.currentY = this.maxY), this.originalTarget.scrollTop = -this.currentY, this.speed *= i.options.friction) : this.stop()
    }, RDSmoothScroll.prototype.initialize = function() {
        t.addEventListener("mousewheel", this.onWheel), t.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", this.onWheel)
    }, RDSmoothScroll.prototype.onWheel = function(i) {
        if (!i.ctrlKey) {
            var o, e, r = t.RDSmoothScroll.instance;
            for (i.preventDefault(), o = i.target; null !== o && "html" != o.nodeName.toLocaleLowerCase() && !(("auto" == t.getComputedStyle(o).getPropertyValue("overflow") || "scroll" == t.getComputedStyle(o).getPropertyValue("overflow")) && o.scrollHeight > o.clientHeight && o.clientHeight > 0);) o = o.parentNode;
            if (null != o) {
                e = r.isAnimator(o) ? r.getAnimator(o) : r.createAnimator(o);
                for (var n in r.animators) r.animators[n] !== e && r.animators[n].stop && r.animators[n].stop();
                e.update(i)
            }
        }
    }, RDSmoothScroll.prototype.createAnimator = function(t) {
        return this.animators[this.animators.push(new RDSmoothScroll.Animator(t)) - 1]
    }, RDSmoothScroll.prototype.isAnimator = function(t) {
        for (var i in this.animators)
            if (this.animators[i].target === t) return !0;
        return !1
    }, RDSmoothScroll.prototype.getAnimator = function(t) {
        for (var i in this.animators)
            if (this.animators[i].target === t) return this.animators[i];
        return o
    }, e || (t.RDSmoothScroll.instance = new RDSmoothScroll)
}(window, document)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested in:

- Google Chrome
- Firefox
- Safari

All of those browsers mentioned above work fine.